# How to either simultaneously delete photo from photo stream and all devices; or

Tags: photos.app, photo-stream

how to designate a photo not to go to the cloud at all.  I'll do something like take a picture of an item at Costco to look it up on the net later.  But I don't want the picture bumped to the cloud, then to my Mac and pad.  It's going to be deleted once it's done it's job.  As it is, I have to delete from my phone, the cloud, the mac and the pad, which gets old.  Or simply leaving them there cluttering up my photos collection.

Comment: I countered the down-vote because I agree that the current setup is a PITA.  If they want to upload the photo automatically and distribute it, then it should also distribute the removal of the pic.  Or the photo should just sit there until you move it to the iCloud folder. I have the EXACT same issue, I take pics of items in stores (or of the kitchen faucet before going to home depot) and these pics end up everywhere, and seem to stick around even after you think they are all deleted.

Answer (score -1):

Turn off the automatic stream button for streaming file from cloud to Mac and iPad, this may work.